# What is the peak output signal power that can be transmitted with this transmitter?

Tags: rf

The following is a tutorial question from radio electronics given by my teacher.

> The output IP3 of the final amplifier in a transmitter is 33 dBm. To reduce the distortion of the transmitted waveforms, this amplifier should operate at a 6 dB back-off mode. What is the peak output signal power that can be transmitted with this transmitter?

Here is what I thought.

The output power of the final amplifier (IP3) is given as 33 dBm, and the amplifier is operating at a 6 dB back-off mode to reduce distortion.

$$Peak \hspace{2mm} Output \hspace{2mm} Power = 33 dBm - 6 dB = 27dBm$$

However, the book said it's  \$ 17.4 dBm\$.

Comment: Back-off is usually defined from P1dB, not IP3.

Comment: @Jason What is P1 here?

Comment: https://www.rfcafe.com/references/electrical/p1db.htm

Comment: You seem to be mixing dbM and dB units. They are different.